# Difference between A* pA = new A; and A* pA = new A();

Tags: c++

in C++, what is the exact difference between both following dynamic object creations :

```
A* pA = new A;

A* pA = new A();
```

I did some tests, but it seems that in both cases, the default constructor is called and only it. I'm looking for any difference about performance...

Thanks

Answer (score 39, accepted):

If `A` is a POD-type, then `new A` will allocate a new `A` object but leave it with an indeterminate value, otherwise `new A` will *default initialize* the new object.

In all cases `new A()` will *value initialize* the new `A` object.

This is obviously different behaviour for POD types but also affects non-POD, non-union class types without a used-declared constructor.

E.g.

```
struct A
{
    int a;
    std::string s;
};
```

`A` is a non-POD class type without a user-declared constructor. When an `A` is *default initialized* the implicitly defined constructor is called which calls the default constructor for `s` (a non-POD type), but `a` is not initialized.

When an `A` is *value initialized*, as it has no used-declared constructor, all of its members are *value initialized* which means that the default constructor for `s` is called and `a` is *zero initialized*.

ISO 14882:2003 references:

- 5.3.4 [expr.new]/15: How objects allocated by a `new` expression are initialized depending on whether the initializer is omitted, a pair of parentheses or otherwise.
- 8.5 [dcl.init]/5: The meaning of *zero initialize*, *default initialize* and *value initialize*.
- 12.1 [class.ctor]/7,8: The form of a user-written constructor that matches the behaviour of an implicitly defined default constructor.
- 12.6.2 [class.base.init]/4: How bases and members which are not listed in a member initializer list of a constructor are initialized.

Comment: and, the wording is actually confusing. What the hell is POD?

Comment: 'Plain old data'. It's a pretty important concept in C++ and the abbreviation is used extensively in the standard. I'm sorry for the confusing wording.

Comment: Note the the concept of "value initialization" was introduced in the revised C++ standard. This also moved the distinction between `new A` and `new A()` to the "has user-declared constructor or not" line. In the original C++ standard (C++98) there was no "value initialization" and the difference between the two was defined by the POD/non-POD property. Depending on the language specification your compiler adheres to, you might get different results. BTW, `struct A` above would be one example.

Answer (score -1):

It's exactly the same, also performance wise :)

Comment: This is simply not true. The two expressions have different effects for both POD-types and non-POD class types without user-defined constructors.