# Validity of int * array = new int [size]();

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, g++, standards

```
int * array = new int [size]();
```

The operator() allow to set all values of array to 0 (all bits to 0). it's called value-initialization.

Since which version of g++ is it valid?

What about other compilers?

Where can I find it in standard?

Comment: This is a syntax error in C. Do you mean the `C` tag to be there?

Comment: This reminds me why I hate C++. Bizarre syntax, secret handshakes, proprietary extensions... a language only a mother could love!

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581763/difference-between-a-pa-new-a-and-a-pa-new-a

Comment: @carl: When it comes to bizarre syntax, C++ had very little to add to C Just think of an off-the-shelf `strcpy` implementation `while(*p1++=*p2++);` - that absurd concatenation of obscure operators makes every novice cringe. (No need to argue, post-increment and dereferencing is certainly obscure to novice programmers.) In the above example, there's no "secret handshake" and no proprietary extension at all. All it does is to allow a safer version of allocating an array of integers, while still allowing users to use the less safe, but slightly faster version. And that's by an ISO standard.

Answer (score 6):

This is part of the C++ standard; if it was invalid in g++ then g++ was nonconforming.  From the C++ standard (ISO/IEC 14882:2003), several sections are relevant:

5.3.4/15 concerning the new expression says:

> If the new-initializer is of the form (), the item is value-initialized

8.5/5 concerning initializers says:

> To value-initialize an object of type T means:
>
> — if T is a class type (clause 9) with a user-declared constructor (12.1), then the default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if T is a non-union class type without a user-declared constructor, then every non-static data member and base-class component of T is value-initialized;
>
> — if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, the object is zero-initialized

So, for an array of ints, which are a scalar type, the third and fourth bullet points apply.

Comment: Thank you ! Since which version of g++ is it valid ?

Answer (score 1):

Initialization with `()` (including your example) was always a part of standard C++, since C++98. Although there were some changes in the newer versions of the standard, they don't apply to your example.

GCC compilers were known to handle `()` initializers incorrectly in versions from 2.x.x family. MSVC++ compiler is known to handle `()` initializers incorrectly in VC6. Newer versions of MSVC++ handle `()` initializers in accordance with C++98 specification.

Comment: Have you sources ? FOr g++ 3.4.3 it seems to fail.

Comment: Hmm.. Works fine in my 3.4.4. How exactly does it fail in 3.4.3? Garbage in the array? Refuses to compile?

Comment: Sorry, its gcc 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-9). It compiles fine,
when i check the elements, array[0], array[1], etc ... they are differents of zero !!!!

Comment: I have no explanation for that. Again, it works fine in my 3.4.4. Are you sure you didn't forget the `()` bit in your experiment?

Answer (score 0):

This is from "Working Draft, Standard for Programming
Language C++" dated 2009-11-09:

**8.5 Initializers**
...
7 To value-initialize an object of type T means:

- if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9) with a user-provided constructor (12.1), then the
  default constructor for T is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if T has no accessible default
  constructor);

  if T is a (possibly cv-qualified) non-union class type without a user-provided constructor, then the object
  is zero-initialized and, if T’s implicitly-declared default constructor is non-trivial, that constructor is
  called.

  if T is an array type, then each element is value-initialized;

  otherwise, the object is zero-initialized.

...