# C++ Instantiate an object from a class two different ways

Tags: c++, object, constructor, instantiation

I'm pretty sure this has been asked before, but I can't for the life of me find it via search.

So here it goes:

What's the difference between:

```
MyObj myObj;
```

and

```
MyObj myObj = MyObj();
```

I believe both achieve the same result, but is one better to use than the other?  Assume all I want is the default constructor.

*edit - I've heard the first is more appropriate as the second first creates an object via the default constructor, then does an assign to myObj.  The first there is no "assign" operation so the first would be "faster". Truth?

Comment: Similar but not quite the same as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581763/difference-between-a-pa-new-a-and-a-pa-new-a

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, there can be a difference.

In the first instance, `myObj` is not initialized if it is a POD type otherwise it is *default-initialized*.

In the second instance `myObj` is *copy-initialized* from a *value-initialized* temporary. The temporary may (and almost certainly should) be eliminated to make the effect *value-initialization*.

If `MyObj` has a constructor then a constructor will always be called. For the first case a default constructor must be accessible, for the second both the copy and default constructors must be accessible although only the default constructor may be called.

In addition to the obvious difference between "not initialized" and *value-initialized* for POD types, there is a difference between *default-initialized* and *value-initialized* for non-POD types with no user-defined constructors. For these types, POD members are not initialized in *default-initialization* but *zero-initialized* in *value-initialization* of the parent class.

Answer (score 4):

The former is a declaration, the latter an initialization.

If MyObj is not a POD then there's really no difference except that a copy constructor must exist and be accessible in the latter case (even though it's not called).

If MyObj is a POD then the former does not initialize it, content of MyObj member variables will be unspecified.  The latter is the only way to 'zero' initialize a non-aggregate POD.

Comment: Have not looked up the standard. But would the second one not be `declaration and initialization`.

Comment: Both of them are declarations, since every definition is a declaration, and both are definitions. The second para of this answer contradicts the last sentence of Charles's answer (this says there's no difference, Charles says there is a difference if the default constructor is compiler-generated). Charles is right, for C++03. In C++98 they're both default constructed.

Answer (score 0):

Without many explanations - The first one uses the default constructor in order to initialize your myObj. The second one actually creates a temporary instance, and then is using a copy constructor to initialize myObj. (remember that a default copy constructor is also created, and not just a default constructor)