# How is the C++ 'new' operator implemented

Tags: c++, new-operator

```
Class B;
B *b  = new B();       // default constructor
B *b1 = new B(10);     // constructor which takes an argument B(int x)
```

However, if we want to write a custom version of `new`, the syntax is

```
Class B
{
  /*...*/
  static void* operator new(size_t size);
}
```

How is the statement `new B()` converted to a function call for 
`operator new(sizeof(B))`?

And how does it keep track of which constructor to call i.e. how does it distinguish between `new B()` and `new B(int x)`?

Is `new` implemented as a macro in C++?

Comment: The work is all done by the compiler knowing how to replace operators and such.

Comment: There is a difference between `new operator` and `operator new`. Check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885849/difference-between-new-operator-and-operator-new

Comment: [There is a difference between `new B()` and `new B`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581763/difference-between-a-pa-new-a-and-a-pa-new-a). There's also a difference between `Class B {}` and `class B {};` - the former has syntax errors, the latter is how you declare classes.

Comment: Just take any c++ book and go to operator overloading

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your question should be:

> How compiler distinguish between `new B()` and `new
>   B(10)`, when the `B::operator new` syntax is same ?

Well, `new` **just allocates the memory** and immediately after that the compiler inserts the call to the constructor. So it's irrespective if you call `new B`, `new B()` or `new B(10)`.

Compiler interprets something like:

```
B *b = static_cast<B*>(B::operator new(sizeof(B)))->B();
B *b1 = static_cast<B*>(B::operator new(sizeof(B)))->B(10);
```

In actual a constructor doesn't return anything. But above pseudo code is just an analogical representation of internal stuff.

Comment: There is C++ syntax for calling a constructor explicitly: `new (B::operator new(sizeof(B))) B()`.

Comment: There is a difference between `new T` and `new T()` for some types. And `operator new` is the one that just allocates memory — ordinary `new` does both allocation and construction, so it's wrong to say it only allocates. There's also placement `new` that only does construction, as mentioned by @Jon (as you can't call the constructor directly).

Comment: @iammilind: I was just offering an example showing how it’s possible to implement yours.

Answer (score 0):

The question of which constructor to call is a matter of overload resolution based on the argument list, similar to any overloaded function call. At the site where new B(...) occurs, all the information is available. The compiler can resolve the reference to class B (name lookup), and see the portfolio of constructors available, and also see that B has a custom memory allocator mechanism. The compiler can emit the code to use that memory allocator to get the space (passing in the size of B), and then invoke appropriate constructor code to initialize the object in that space.