# size_t parameter new operator

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, new-operator

I have a point in my mind which I can't figure out about new operator overloading.
Suppose that, I have a class MyClass yet MyClass.h MyClass.cpp and main.cpp files are like;

```
//MyClass.h

class MyClass {
   public:
     //Some member functions
     void* operator new (size_t size);
     void operator delete (void* ptr);
     //...
};

//MyClass.cpp

void* MyClass::operator new(size_t size) {
   return malloc(size);
}

void MyClass::operator delete(void* ptr) {
   free(ptr);
}

//main.cpp

//Include files
//...

int main() {
   MyClass* cPtr = new MyClass();
   delete cPtr
}
```

respectively. This program is running just fine. However, the thing I can't manage to understand is, how come new operator can be called without any parameter while in its definition it has a function parameter like "size_t size". Is there a point that I am missing here?
Thanks.

Comment: The compiler passes the size automagically

Comment: [look at this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9595758/how-is-the-c-new-operator-implemented)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't confuse the "new expression" with the "operator new" allocation function. The former causes the latter. When you say `T * p = new T;`, then this calls the allocation function first to obtain memory and then *constructs* the object in that memory. The process is loosely equivalent to the following:

```
void * addr = T::operator new(sizeof(T));    //  rough equivalent of what
T * p = ::new (addr) T;                      //  "T * p = new T;" means.
```

(Plus an exception handler in the event that the constructor throws; the memory will be deallocated in that case.)

Answer (score 1):

The new-expression `new MyClass()` is basically defined in two steps. First it calls the allocator function, which you have overloaded, to get some allocated memory. It passes the size of the type `MyClass` to that allocator function, which is why the `size_t` argument is required. After this, it constructs an object in that allocated memory and returns a pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler knows the size of your class.  Basically, it's passing `sizeof(MyClass)` into your `new` function.