# How is my overloaded new getting called when no argument is provided?

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading, new-operator

In the output `new called` is printed when the statement `Test *m = new Test();` is executed.  But we are not passing any argument to the user-defined `new` function.

Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

class Test {
public:
    void* operator new(size_t size);
    void operator delete(void*);
    Test() { cout<<"\n Constructor called"; }
    ~Test() { cout<<"\n Destructor called"; }
};

void* Test::operator new(size_t size)
{
    cout<<"\n new called";
    void *storage = malloc(size);
    return storage;
}

void Test::operator delete(void *p )
{
    cout<<"\n delete called";
    free(p);
}

int main()
{
    Test *m = new Test();
    delete m;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Magic? (of the sort that passes `sizeof(Test)`)

Comment: The magic of compilers..

Comment: Same way you don't give `operator++(int)` an `int`.

Comment: So the "problem" here is simply failing to understand the very `operator new` that *you're* overriding?

Comment: Beside a terrible title, this isn't a bad question.  Saying "Magic" and "The same way x happens" doesn't help.  I expect better.

Comment: That's how overloading the `new` operator works. The `size` argument is passed to `operator new` by the compiler.

Comment: @Grammin: I wasn't answering the question, really (although I did attempt to qualify the magic). An answer would likely be along the lines of, "the compiler calls `new` with the size of the allocated object by default". Which I probably won't post as I'm actively looking for a duplicate question, assuming one exists.

Comment: @UpAndAdam: No. That doesn't appear to answer this question, which appears to be about where the size argument came from. (unfortunately `new` questions are hard to find)

Comment: @Hasturkun good point sorry about that! :-) thought someone would actually accept only an answer that actually explained it!  Yours looks good though! and suprisingly similar to my downvoted answer..

Comment: @UpAndAdam: Well, it looks like a misleading title, that question was about how an apparently non-static method is being found. The accepted answer fits that perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is also roughly what Kerrick goes over in [size_t parameter new operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16640309/size-t-parameter-new-operator)

Implicitly there is a call to `Test::new(sizeof(Test))` to obtain the memory for keyword new to provide to the constructor to use.

So while you don't realize it you actually are calling it.  You can use a debugger and stack trace to figure this out or the documents regarding overriding the new operator and how constructors work.

> The relationship between Operator New and the New Keyword
>
> Don't be confused by the fact that there is both a new keyword and an
>   operator new. When you write: MyClass *x = new MyClass; there are
>   actually two things that happen--memory allocation and object
>   construction; the new keyword is responsible for both. One step in the
>   process is to call operator new in order to allocate memory; the other
>   step is to actually invoke the constructor. Operator new lets you
>   change the memory allocation method, but does not have any
>   responsibility for calling the constructor. That's the job of the new
>   keyword.

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/operator_new.html

Comment: Dude, why'd everyone downvote this one so much?

Comment: @ash That's what I'd like to know! Even in the edit history I only made it more complete never changed the correctness...

Comment: You might want to reorder the contents of your answer somewhat. (also, "Yes you are" is a bit odd)

Comment: @ash There was an error in the previous version - it used to say an anonymous `Test()` object was being created. In reality, no object has been created, as `operator new` has to allocate the memory for the object, which is then created. At least that's how I (and the downvoters) must have read it. I upvoted it as soon as you fixed that, though.

Comment: @Alex Fair enough I can see how that would be misunderstood, but the point was still the same.. but its usually good to comment :-)

Comment: @Hasturkun Thanks for the pointer, reordered it and reworded again.  Yes you are was better than you can't not call it I thought. Probably could have benefitted from a smiley.