# C++ declare an object with parenthesis

Tags: c++, constructor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error on calling default constructor with empty set of brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/180172/error-on-calling-default-constructor-with-empty-set-of-brackets)

I have a testing program attached.
Question:

If I declare like the following, there is no objected created and
the default constructor is not called.
 'grCell c3();'  // bad

However, 
Declare like this is OK. An object is created and its constructor is called.
 'grCell c1;' // good

What is the difference between 'grCell c3()' and 'grCell c1' ?

Thanks!

Todd

//---- BEGIN -------

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

typedef unsigned int uint;
using namespace std; 

//
class grCell {
 public:
  grCell()      { printf("HERE_0\n"); };
  grCell(int i) { printf("HERE_1\n"); };
  ~grCell() {};

  void setX(int x) { _x = x; }
  //
  //
private:


  int  _x:22;
};

int main()
{

  grCell c1;  // good
  c1.setX(100);


  grCell c3();  // bad
  c3.setX(100);

  grCell c2(5);
  c2.setX(10);


}
```

//------ END ------

Answer (score 7):

> **What is the difference between `grCell c3()` and `grCell c1` ?**

The first declares a function while the second creates an object named `c1` of the type `grCell`.

```
grCell c3();
```

It does not create an object but declares a function with the name `c3` which takes no arguments and returns an object of type `grCell`.
It is the **[Most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)** in C++.

Comment: and then of course the *next* line causes a compiler error because the `c3` function doesn't have a `setX()` member.

Answer (score 5):

You have encountered [the most vexing parse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

`grCell c3()` declares a **function** named `c3` which returns a `grCell`.

`grCell c3` declares an instance of `grCell` named `c3`.

In C++, there is a saying, "anything the looks like a function, is a function".

**Concerning the comment**

`grCell()` is called value initialization, both `grCell()` and `grCell` invoke the default constructor if it is class type. However, `int()` and `int` are different, the first version zero initializes the object.

Comment: grCell *p1 = new grCell(); // OK
    grCell *p2 = new grCell;   // OK

Comment: @user1273456: `new` is a C++ keyword, and `new grCell()` is on the right hand side of an expression which uses `operator=`, it is impossible to treat that as a function.

Comment: @JesseGood Can you please tell me the difference between `new grCell()` and `new grCell`? I am pretty new to C++ btw.

Comment: @Suri: [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1581763/difference-between-a-pa-new-a-and-a-pa-new-a) which explains it.